# How to extract column header from matching row value in a separate DataFrame and create a new column based off that?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I need to map a certain column’s values and create a new column that matches what I need, and I came up with a solution by creating a DataFrame out of the 1-to-many mapping dict that I'll be using. The issue is, I’m not sure how to perform the mapping itself, where I find the corresponding row + column in the “Mapping” DF and extract the column header, then create a new column based off that.

Base DF:

```
    Event Name  Event Type
0   Hello       A
1   Hi          D
2   Yes         C
```

Mapping DF:

```
    Good Event  Bad Event
0   A           B
1   C           D
2   E           F
```

Resulting DF:

```
    Event Name  Event Type    Original Event Type
0   Hello       Good Event    A
1   Hi          Bad Event     D
2   Yes         Good Event    C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below df's:

```
In [1274]: base_df
Out[1274]: 
  Event_Name Event_Type
0      Hello          A
1         Hi          D
2        Yes          C

In [1263]: mapping_df
Out[1263]: 
  Good_Event Bad_Event
0          A         B
1          C         D
2          E         F

In [1277]: mapping = {v:k for i in mapping_df.to_dict('records') for k,v in i.items()}

In [1276]: base_df['New event type'] = base_df.Event_Type.map(mapping)

In [1279]: base_df
Out[1279]: 
  Event_Name Event_Type New event type
0      Hello          A     Good_Event
1         Hi          D      Bad_Event
2        Yes          C     Good_Event
```